# Upload file from my virtual machine to another virtual machine using hadoop hdfs

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-12.04, hdfs

Can any one please tell me, how can I upload a txt file from my local machine to another virtual machine based on IP Address in hdfs.

Regards,
Baskar.V

Comment: Do your local machine install the hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

You might find webHDFS REST API useful. I have tried it to write content from my local FS to the HDFS and it works fine. But being REST based it should work fine from local FS of a remote machine as well, provided both machines are connected.